# Batching and the APIs - Performance

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

i'm making my calls from google apps script.

I'm having a strange problem. For create, batching is very fast (like 4 seconds for 20 records and I haven't tried more).

Copy file, however, is super slow. It gets a batch api time out if there are more than 20 records and those 20 records take about 58 seconds. So 3 seconds per file, which is (after many hours of work) the same speed that I get with a basic for loop and driveapp.copy calls. Worse, actually, because at least if I'm using a for-loop I can run for 30 minutes not 60 seconds.

Is there some way to speed it up? Something I'm not keeping in mind?

```
function COPYBATCH(dictionary) {
  var body = [];
  for (var key in dictionary)

    {
      var object = {
      method: "POST",
      endpoint: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/"+dictionary[key].source+"/copy",
      requestBody: {
        "parents": [
           dictionary[key].parent,
        ],

         "name": key 
      }     

      };
      body.push(object);
    }
  Logger.log(body.length);

  var boundary = "xxxxxxxxxx";
  var contentId = 0;
  var data = "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
  for (var i in body) {
        data += "Content-Type: application/http\r\n";
        data += "Content-ID: " + ++contentId + "\r\n\r\n";
        data += body[i].method + " " + body[i].endpoint + "\r\n";
        data += body[i].requestBody ? "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n" : "\r\n";
        data += body[i].requestBody ? JSON.stringify(body[i].requestBody) + "\r\n" : "";
        data += "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
  }
  var payload = Utilities.newBlob(data).getBytes();
  var options = {
    method: "post",
    contentType: "multipart/mixed; boundary=" + boundary,
    payload: payload,
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  };
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/batch/drive/v3", options).getContentText();
  Logger.log(res);
  return parseResponseArray(res,dictionary);

}
```

Things I've tried: I initially had my batch fetching from /batch/ but I found on the best practices page for the gmail api that it should be more specific. The response only includes the fileid, the name, and the mimetype, so restricting the returned fields doesn't SEEM like it will be very useful.

Actually restricting it to `"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/"+dictionary[key].source+"/copy?fields=id,name",`
seems to have given me a few more records per minute but not many, I still can't copy 30 files without it blowing the api timeout.

Comment: In my environment, I have never experienced. So in order to correctly understand about your situation, can I ask you about the mimeType and file size of 30 files? Because I thought that if the file size is large, such error might occur. But I think that this is required to be tested.

Comment: its a mix of gsheets , pdfs, and gdocs with a couple of large zips thrown in. You think the size makes a difference?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that it was yes. But I have never tested this. So I have to apologize for my poor experience.

Comment: The only reason to use batching would be to save you the HTTP calls on multiple calls to the API.  I have never been a fan of batching for all of the reasons you have stated.  Batching is not going to be faster, batching does not improve your quota usage, batching can result in running to fast quota errors as its the same user preforming each of the batch requests and if the server is fast for once then you will get a flood protection error.

Comment: Do your PDFs and zips collectively exceed 50MB in your batch request? [`UrlFetchApp` has a max quota of 50MB on POST requests...](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations)

Comment: Thanks Dimu, today i'll experiment with smaller files and see what happens

Comment: Do google documents with no known size (the size doesn't show up in drive, cant be pulled by program) count against that 50mb limit?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, where you are only uploading 20 files, a batch upload doesn't give you a noticeable advantage over multiple single files uploads on loop. Nevertheless, it is the best practice possible and there is nothing more that you can do to speed it up, except optimize the code so it can be interpreted faster. You can read the [batch documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch) to avoid hitting its limits and gather more detailed information.

Comment: Well when I do more than the 20 files it is sending back a timeout error after 60 seconds.... is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: In that case I strongly suggest to split the files over single file uploads. If you really want to user batch files, the solution is to splits the batch in smaller batches.